# Zend Framework URL with ".jpg" at the end

Tags: php, zend-framework

(Possible it works as designed, but I'm sure it was working before updating to **ZF 1.11.x**.)

I am trying to "print" an image to the browser, but when I construct the URL like this:

```
webserver/index/get-image/PARAM1/xyz/IMAGE/1.jpg
```

I get a **404** error from the server

```
webserver/index/get-image/IMAGE/1.jpg/PARAM1/xyz
```

Works..

Any ideas?

Comment: What controller/action do you want to be invoked by your desired url? Are you creating any custom routes or just using the default routes?

Comment: index Controller/ getImageAction, just the default route

Comment: just a quick idea, I don't have the sources to check atm: were there any changes to the .htaccess in /public ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 404-error is most likely because you've defined in the web server rules (e.g. .htaccess) that urls ending with .jpg should not be rewritten to index.php (e.g. `RewriteRule ^[\w/\%]*(?:\.(?!(?:js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|html)$)[\w\%]*$)? /index.php [I]`)

When using Apache, the following should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

For more information, go to http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html

Comment: Thanks forgot the tiny htaccess file :-)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is one more difference in the two urls and it is the get-image action (I assume it is an action if it is ZF). Try to add or remove the action also on the second link and post back the results.

Answer (score 0):

Try Zend_Route as follows

```
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
    'images/:img',
    array(
        'controller' => 'index',
        'action'     => 'getImageAction'
    )
);

$router->addRoute('user', $route);
```

and now when you go to server/images/pic1.jpg, you will have a param (retrieve through `$this->getRequest->getParam('img')` from you Controller) available for whatever you wish for. GL

EDIT: I see now this wasn't your problem exactly, but this might be a fruitful workaround anyhow.